# Login using Azure Authentication in a React app

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create an app which has login with Azure authentication

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {UserAgentApplication} from 'msal';
import {Config} from './Config';
import { getUserDetails } from './GraphService';
import WelcomePage from './WelcomePage';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

// Initialize the MSAL application object
  this.userAgentApplication=new UserAgentApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: Config.appId,
      redirectUri: Config.redirectUri
     },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
      storeAuthStateInCookie: true
    }
  })

  this.state = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {},
    error: null,
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  // If MSAL already has an account, the user
  // is already logged in
  let account=this.userAgentApplication.getAccount();
  

  if(account) {
    this.getUserProfile()
  }
}

getUserProfile=async ()=>{
  try {
    // Get the access token silently
    // If the cache contains a non-expired token, this function
    // will just return the cached token. Otherwise, it will
    // make a request to the Azure OAuth endpoint to get a token

    var accessToken=await this.userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent({
      scopes: ["user.read"]
    });

    if(accessToken) {
      console.log(accessToken);
      // Get the user's profile from Graph
      var user=await getUserDetails(accessToken);

      this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: {
          displayName: user.displayName,
          email: user.mail || user.userPrincipalName
        },
        error: null
      })
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    let error={}
    if(typeof(err)==='string') {
      let errParts=err.split("|");
      error=errParts.length>1 
      ? 
        {
          message: errParts[1],
          debug: errParts[0]
        }
      : { message: err}
    }
    else {
      error= {
        message: err.message,
        debug: JSON.stringify(err)
      }
    }

    this.setState({
      isAuthenticated: false,
      user: {},
      error: error
    })
  }
}


login=async ()=>{
  try {
    await this.userAgentApplication.loginPopup({
      scopes: Config.scopes.logout,
      prompt: "select_account"
    })
    await this.getUserProfile()
  }
  catch (err) {
    var error={}

    if(typeof(err)==='string') {
      let errParts=err.split("|");
      error=errParts.length>1 
      ? 
        {
          message: errParts[1],
          debug: errParts[0]
        }
      :
        {
          message: err
        }
    }
    else {
      error={
        message: err.message,
        debug: JSON.stringify(err)
      }
    }

    this.setState({
      isAuthenticated: false,
      user: {},
      error: error
    })
  }
}

logoutBtn=()=>{ this.userAgentApplication.logout() }

render() {
  let cbsContent=null
  const {isAuthenticated, user}=this.state;

  if(isAuthenticated) {
    cbsContent=( <div>authenticated</div> )
  }
  else {
    cbsContent=(
      <WelcomePage
        isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
        user={this.state.user}
        authButtonMethod={this.login}
      />
    )
  }
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        {cbsContent}
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
}

  export default withRouter(App);
```

Config.js

```
export const Config={
  authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common',
  appId: <my app id>,          //localhost
  redirectUri: 'https://localhost:3000',

  scopes: [
    'user.read.all',
  ]
};
```

GraphService.js

```
import {Client} from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client';

const getAuthenticatedClient=(accessToken)=>{
  const client=Client.init({
      authProvider: (done)=>{
          done(null, accessToken.accessToken)
      }
  });
  return client
  }

//User details
  export const getUserDetails=async (accessToken)=>{
    const client=getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);

    const user=await client.api('/me').get();
    return user;
 }
```

WelcomePage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button} from 'reactstrap';

class Welcome extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>CourtRoom Booking System</h2>
                <div><Button color='primary' onClick={this.props.authButtonMethod}>
                    Sign in</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
    }

export default Welcome;
```

I have set the application as multi tenant, so every mail id which has o365 acccount should access my application.
But when I try signin with an email different from my organization, I don't receive any token object, hence user is'nt authenticated and hence the user cant login into my application

What other setting I should change in my app, or any other permission I should give, any pointers will be really helpful

Comment: While registering your application have you select the supported account type as `Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)`.  and while logging in with user credentials did it ask for any admin consent approval. Can you share the error message you are receiving while signing-in

Comment: For my registered application, i have selected the option   "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)"

while logging with user id, after giving credentials, the popup just exited, but I didnt receive any token..It show no error in the popup

Thanks for the response

Comment: Can you provided us the code sample/document which you are refering will try to repro the issue and in the mean time Can you once check the Console log whether any error are returned there

Comment: i am following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/react

but instead of typescript, i am writing js files..
Also, while running the application, the console was on, but it didnt show any error in the console.

Comment: I have not replicated the link completely, i just want the user to get an access token and login should be successful

Comment: Hi did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Looks like there is something wrong with the `msal 1.2.1` package installed by `npm install`.

I resolved it by re-installing `msal 1.2.1`.

```
npm uninstall msal@1.2.1

npm install msal@1.2.1 

npm run-script build  

npm start
```

Hope it also applies to your situation.